# No orders in user profile with custom state of order-status

Tags: 6, ubercart

Drupal 6 + Ubercart. I had created some new order statuses with own state. But when order gets this status, order dissapears from user "Ordered products" (in user's profile)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Order History page (user/%user/orders) [retrieves orders](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ubercart/tree/uc_order/uc_order.admin.inc#n888) that are `general` in scope.

If you created a custom Status through **/admin/store/settings/orders/edit/workflow/create**, this scope excludes *Canceled* & *In Checkout* statuses. If you've created a custom state through [`hook_uc_order_state()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_order%21uc_order.api.php/function/hook_uc_order_state/7), you need to the `scope` to `general` for it show up.